# Как совместить Take и Skip?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть список. Хочу из него брать каждые 10 элементов и вставлять в List

Есть вариант делать в цикле `for`, но более интересен вариант реализации через `Linq`

```
var keyList = new List<KeyGroup>();
var list = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   KeyGroup key = new KeyGroup();
   key.Value1 = list[i].Split(' ')[0];
   key.Value2 = list[i].Split(' ')[1];
   keyList.Add(key);
}
```

Comment: Вам надо один большой список из M элементов разбить на N списков по 10 элементов? А что если `M % 10 != 0`?

Comment: А как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, вам нужно `Batch` из пакета MoreLinq. Он как раз умеет выдавать вам элементы списка пачками по `n` штук.

Вот такой код:

```
using MoreLinq;
// ...

var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 95).ToList();
foreach (var ten in list.Batch(10))
{
    Console.WriteLine("[ " + string.Join(" ", ten) + " ]");
}
```

даёт

```
[ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
[ 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ]
[ 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 ]
[ 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 ]
[ 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 ]
[ 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 ]
[ 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 ]
[ 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 ]
[ 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 ]
[ 90 91 92 93 94 ]
```

Не забудьте [подключить `MoreLinq` через nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/).