# Как ускорить цикл?

Tags: c#, производительность

Во входном файле ~650тыс строк. Каждые десять строк я вставляю в класс KeyGroup и добавляю его в список `lst`. Все бы ничего, да скорость ну оооочень медленная. Я думал использую оперативку оно будет быстрее работать. Какой кусок кода можно оптимизировать?

```
 var data = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
 var lst = new List<KeyGroup>();

 for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i += 10)
     {
           KeyGroup key = new KeyGroup();
           key.key = data[i].Split('\t')[1];
           key.url =data.Take(i + 10).Skip(i).ToList().Select(x => x.Split('\t')[0]).ToList();
           key.used = false;
           lst.Add(key);
      }

public class KeyGroup
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public bool used { get; set; }
        public List<string> url { get; set; }

       public KeyGroup()
        {
              url = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: внутри цикла можно убрать один `ToList` который внутри строки, ну и вторая проблема - похоже тут ошибка `data.Take(i + 10).Skip(i)` должно сначала вызываться `Skip`, хотя тут не уверен, а вот то, что каждый раз в этом случае происходит бег с начала коллекции - основная проблема

Comment: почему не воспользовались решением из [этого ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523447/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-take-%D0%B8-skip)?

Comment: А что вам конкретно нужно сделать?

Comment: Пример данных из исходного файла можете выложить?

Comment: Очень медленная - это какая? Какой размер файла? Он находится на локальном жёстком диске или на сетевом? Если на локальном - то это HDD или SSD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мой вам совет - если над вами не стоит начальство, кричащее "LINQ это модно-молодежно, он должен быть везде!" - не используйте в своём коде LINQ:

```
const string FILE_NAME = @"test.txt";
const char SEPARATOR = '\t';

var result = new List<KeyGroup>();
string[] line;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(FILE_NAME))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var group = new KeyGroup();

        line = reader.ReadLine().Split(SEPARATOR);
        group.key = line[1];
        group.used = false;

        group.url = new List<string>();
        group.url.Add(line[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine().Split(SEPARATOR);
            group.url.Add(line[0]);
        }

        result.Add(group);
    }
}
```

На тестовом наборе данных(1 миллион строк - 100 тысяч груп сгенированных по образу и подобию ваших - текстовый файл на 80 мегабайт) у меня этот код отрабатывает меньше чем за 0.1 секунды, в то время как вашему потребовалось около 4 минут.

Основное время у вас занимают вызовы ToList() в этой строке:

```
key.url = data.Take(i + 10).Skip(i).ToList().Select(x => x.Split('\t')[0]).ToList();
```

Но ковырятся в недрах .NET, выясняя почему он так долго выполняется - у меня нет ни желания, ни времени. Ваш код сейчас очень тяжело поддерживать, и я не вижу абсолютно никакого смысла добиватся здесь применения LINQ.

LINQ не умеет групировать по индексу элемента - в этом основная сложность. Можно конечно искуственно добавить индекс, и групировать по нему:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
    .Select((line, index) => new { line, index })
    .GroupBy(element => element.index / 10)
    .Select(group => group.Select(element => element.line))
    .Select(group => new KeyGroup()
    {
        key = group.First().Split(SEPARATOR)[1],
        url = new List<string>(group.Select(element => element.Split(SEPARATOR)[0])),
        used = false
    });
```

Но согласитесь - не смотря на сравнимую скорость работы, это гораздо более непонятный и сложнее поддерживаемый код, нежели предложенный изначально? LINQ тут только создаёт ненужные сложности, не давая каких-либо приемуществ.

Comment: все проблема в _Take(i + 10).Skip(i)_ - они пробегаются с начала последовательности каждый раз

Comment: @Grundy, ну да, Но всё равно - без LINQ решение этой задачи проще и очевиднее )

Answer (score 2):

В защиту LINQ скажу, что вы его неправильно готовите.

LINQ нужно применять сознательно, понимая, что и для чего, тогда у вас будет понятный и быстрый код.

Для вашего случая, как уже говорилось в похожих обсуждениях, стоит воспользоваться функцией `Batch` из MoreLinq.

Получаем следующий простой и симпатичный код:

```
var data = File.ReadLines(@"test.txt");
var result = data.Batch(10, ConvertBatchToKeyGroup).ToList();
```

с дополнительной функцией `ConvertBatchToKeyGroup`, которая генерирует из десяти строк одну штуку `KeyGroup`:

```
static KeyGroup ConvertBatchToKeyGroup(IEnumerable<string> batch)
{
    var keygroup = new KeyGroup() { used = false };
    var first = true;
    foreach (var s in batch)
    {
        var parts = s.Split('\t');
        if (first)
        {
            keygroup.key = parts[1];
            first = false;
        }
        keygroup.url.Add(parts[0]);
    }
    return keygroup;
}
```

---

Я даже не поленился провести бенчмарк (в первой версии была ошибка, скорректировал). Я создал файл в 10 раз больше вашего следующим кодом:

```
static Random r = new Random();

static string GetRandomString()
{
    var l = r.Next(1, 10);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(l);
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        sb.Append(GetRandomChar());
    return sb.ToString();
}

static string validChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
static char GetRandomChar()
{
    var c = validChars[r.Next(validChars.Length)];
    if (r.Next(2) == 1)
        return char.ToUpper(c);
    else
        return c;
}

static void Generate()
{
    using (var f = File.CreateText(@"test.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 650000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                f.WriteLine(GetRandomString() + "\t" + GetRandomString());
        }
    }
}
```

На нём LINQ-решение из пяти пробегов (вне IDE, VS 2015, Release) дало следующие результаты:

```
Test took 00:00:03.0970144
Test took 00:00:03.0980258
Test took 00:00:03.1139645
Test took 00:00:03.0844650
Test took 00:00:03.0531891
```

Тестовый код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    M3();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Test took {sw.Elapsed}");
}

static void M3()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method #3");
    var data = File.ReadLines(@"test.txt");
    var result = data.Batch(10, ConvertBatchToKeyGroup).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
}
```

На тех же данных, в аналогичных условиях тест для метода из альтернативного решения, без LINQ, показал такие результаты:

```
Test took 00:00:02.9599368
Test took 00:00:02.9154132
Test took 00:00:02.9102364
Test took 00:00:02.8727285
Test took 00:00:02.9275071
```

— то есть, сравнимо с LINQ.

---

А где же ошибки у вас? Их много.

1. `File.ReadAllLines` читает весь файл в память. Это слишком расходно, т. к. требуется выделение всей памяти, которая потом всё равно будет не нужна. Лучше: `File.ReadLines`, который читает файл ленивым образом, и не нагружает память.
2. Цикл до `data.Count()` — пересчёт количества в цикле каждый раз не нужен. (Он, правда, быстрый, поскольку вы всё равно считали весь массив в память.)
3. `data.Take(i + 10).Skip(i).ToList().Select(x => x.Split('\t')[0]).ToList();` — ужасный ужас, хуже не бывает. `data.Take(i + 10).Skip(i)` пробегает по всему списку от 0 до `i + 10`, чтобы найти нужный элемент! То есть у вас получается квадратичная скорость обработки! Затем вы почему-то материализуете список (лишняя аллокация, хотя и всего 10 элементов), чтобы тут же дематериализовать его. Это всё не нужно.